# Custom route constraint not working in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, constraints, subdomain

I can't manage to make my route constraint to work in Rails 4. Here's my routes file:

```
Catapult::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints Subdomain do
    resources :contacts do
      member do
        get 'delete'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the subdomain constraint:

```
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    p request.subdomains.first # This never appears in the logs
    request.subdomains.first !~ /www|catapultcentral|customercube|lvh/
  end
end
```

As noted in the code above, the output of the `p` statement never appears in the logs and the
constraint never seems to be applied. This is the output of `rake routes`:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
delete_contact GET    /contacts/:id/delete(.:format) contacts#delete
      contacts GET    /contacts(.:format)            contacts#index
               POST   /contacts(.:format)            contacts#create
   new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)        contacts#new
  edit_contact GET    /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)   contacts#edit
       contact GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)        contacts#show
               PATCH  /contacts/:id(.:format)        contacts#update
               PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)        contacts#update
               DELETE /contacts/:id(.:format)        contacts#destroy
```

The constraint doesn't appear in the output either...

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score -1):

I think you may need to use an instance of your constraint class, you have to call Subdomain.new:

```
Catapult::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints Subdomain.new do
    resources :contacts do
      member do
        get 'delete'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This means that `matches?` shouldn't be a class-method but an instance-method:

```
class Subdomain
  def matches?(request)
    request.subdomains.first !~ /www|catapultcentral|customercube|lvh/
  end
end
```